# Visual Studio Code (vscode) - Request textDocument/documentLink failed error on key press

Tags: html, jsp, visual-studio-code

Hi I'm running VSCode on my mac and Windows 10 machine. They've both started displaying the same symptoms after the latest update/rollback.

Every couple of keypresses I get the output box appear, with the "HTML Language Server" selected in the dropdown. The error displayed is:

```
[Error - 13:47:09] Request textDocument/documentLink failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/documentLink failed with message: Path must be a string. Received undefined
  Code: -32603
```

This gets repeated indefinetly and is making VSCode unusable. I'm editing some JSP / JSTL files so I'm wondering if it's some non-valid HTML setting it off, but this has never been an issue before.

All research I've found of this error seems to suggest a faulty extension, but I've currently not got any installed.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue and, as per this [Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15018), the workaround is to open Visual Studio Code on a folder instead of a file.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this popping up this morning, google pointed me to vscode's extensions, so I went through the vscode extensions, updated them all and Debugger for Chrome (2.2.0) was the only one fitting the Error message.

Since I do not have the time right now to file an issue (and answer follow-ups) on https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues I have just disabled the extension for now.

One thing to note is, while vscode says it is version 2.2.2 in the extension panel, it is 2.2.0 on its marketplace page and github. Might be of some interest to dive in and find out where the extension panel picks up its - false - version number - and find out whether this has some impact on creating the error.