# VS Code - Request textDocument/definition failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I really like VS Code, which I use primarily for JS and React (jsx). Sometimes when I code, a panel pops up with a message:

`[Error - 13:45:45] Request textDocument/definition failed.
  Message: Request textDocument/definition failed with message: Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of undefined
  Code: -32603`

How can get rid of this error message or prevent opening a panel when `Request textDocument/definition failed`?

Comment: Can you reproduce the error or is it hit and miss?

Comment: It happens randomly

Comment: Can you tell us which version of VS Code are you using?

Comment: Feels like a bad plugin to me. Disable all the plugins you have going and see what happens.

Comment: ^^ This.  Will definitely be an extension.

Comment: @staypuftman I use more than 30 plugins. Do you think VS Code is able to generate a log file? It would be easier to find out which plugin throws the error

Comment: Looks like you have to turn on logging: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10649

Comment: @staypuftman Can you post it as an answer and I can award it. Thanks

Comment: For me, the error comes from C:\Users\...\.vscode\extensions\pivotal.vscode-spring-boot-1.8.0\node_modules\vscode-jsonrpc\lib\main.js:517:40. Should have never installed that vs code update...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you see strange errors like your `Request textDocument/definition failed` in any ecosystem with plugins, the best place to start hunting is in the error logs of that application. Errors like this normally show up when you update the core application, which will shift its own API enough to break contrib code like this.

In terms of VS Code specifically, it requires you turn on logging within the `Help -> Toggle Developer Tools` menu, which then creates logs you can go scan.

Looks like you found the error pretty easily in the [tern.js](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hsiaosiyuan0.ternjs) plugin you were using, but the same general flow for debugging big ecosystems like node.js, React and others follow this same pattern.

Comment: I want to code and debug my own code, not manage my ecosystem of tools and debug their problems. At least they should not get in my way. How can I just ignore the error message or stop it from putting the Output window over my terminal?

Comment: Best solution is to roll back to a previous VS Code version, find the plugin and either push a PR up to the plugin or submit an issue on their Github page.

Answer (score 4):

Quick google and found a SO link which says this is a know issue and a workaround is to open Visual Studio Code on a folder instead of a file.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40631794/1249386

GitHub link : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15018
Let me know if this help you or not?

Comment: Matt, glad you found the answer your self. but what about the bounty then lol :)

Comment: Matt, Okay.. I think u will give me

Comment: sorry, but staypuftman's answer was exactly what I needed and what helped me. Hope, your answer will help someone else

Comment: Matt, Understood.. I was just kiddding... :)

Answer (score 0):

Could that be the [vetur Plugin](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/134)? It seems to have some language issues.

Answer (score 0):

Logger says [tern.js](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hsiaosiyuan0.ternjs) plugin throws this error. Since I disabled this plugin, I don't see error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue which was caused by the **Dart plugin for Flutter.** And resolved by [deleting the .dartsever folder](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/47736#issuecomment-1812562013)